# Adding a favicon - not working

Tags: html, favicon

I try to add favicon to my site.
I am upload the favicon to directory index and I add this line to my header site:

```
<link rel="icon" href="http://example.com/favicon.ico">
```

Maybe its chache?
help me please :)

edit:
I am dont see request to favicon :O
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DET3.png

Any-asnwer not working..

## **Maybe I need clear chache?**

## EDIT: THIS IS WORKING NOW, THANKS FOR ALL!

Comment: Try this... `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://example.com/favicon.ico">`

Comment: @ShrinivasShukla not working .. :(

Comment: Try to load the same path on browser by typing into the address bar or just see the network panel for any error in loading

Comment: take my advice and save it as a jpg or use the generator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your favicon may be the wrong bit depth and/or size. Save your favicon as an 8bit (jpg is 8-bit, but png is better and you can save for web as 8-bit, it doesn't need to be .ico) image and make sure to clear your cache. On upload, it should show in all browsers. Save it as ideally 16x16 pixels

Comment: I am know it .. The type of my icon is "ico"

Comment: try uploading the image again to the link and re-uploading it

Comment: great! glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://example.com/favicon.ico" />
```

Comment: Not working..!? Whats its showing in console. any 404 not found or anything like hat?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
<link rel='shortcut icon' type='image/x-icon' href='favicon.ico' />
```

Put your favicon icon on root directory.

Also ensure that the favicon icon exists at the url("http://example.com/favicon.ico")

Answer (score 0):

Do you see your favicon when opening `http://example.com/favicon.ico` ?

If you do, try to reload the page `http://example.com/` with `CTRL + R`

Comment: Download this favicon and insert it into your root directory to see if your favicon is invalid or the code

http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico

Answer (score 0):

Try this Sure it will work

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon.png"/>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="http://eg.com/favicon.png"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another way you can do this

FoYou need to upload the favicon file “favicon.ico” to the server. To do so, point your browser address bar to your FTP server. Your URL might look similar to this:

“ftp: //username @ websitedesign.com”

When you press enter, the browser will prompt you seeking an username and password. Once you get access to the root folder, upload your favicon file into it.

Now, you need to edit the HTML page of your website to help browsers fetch your favicon image while displaying your web page.

To do this, keep your FTP window open and download the “index.html” or “header.php” file from server and follow the steps below according to the file you get:

Now, insert the code below in the HEAD area of the “index.html” file, and  change “yourwebsite.com” for your own website address.